# R when an assignment (a<-b) could return FALSE if b cannot return FALSE

Tags: r, syntax

I found a very strange syntax in the R function bw.nrd0

```
bw.nrd0_test <- function (x)

{

    if(length(x) < 2L) stop("need at least 2 data points")

    hi <- sd(x)

    if(!(lo <- min(hi, IQR(x1)/1.34)))# qnorm(.75) - qnorm(.25) = 1.34898

        (lo <- hi) || (lo <- abs(x[1L])) || (lo <- 1.)

    0.9 * lo * length(x)^(-0.2)

}
```

When an assignment could return FALSE? I don't think that the min() function could return FALSE in any case.
I get the syntax below that tries the three assignments one after the other, and that the first that works win, but again when something like lo <- hi could return FALSE if hi cannot be FALSE?

I tried to raise errors in the functions but I get an error that breaks the condition, not FALSE.

Comment: `if(!numeric_object))` returns false if `numeric_object!=0`

Comment: are you using the assignment operator `<-` as a comparator `<` ?

Comment: no, I'm not using it as a comparator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, while `min` probably can't return a boolean, we don't necessarily need a boolean for an "if" clause. Now combine that with R implicitly returning the last value of an operation we get the behavior that was exploited for this function.

From `?bw.nrd0`:

> It defaults to 0.9 times the
> minimum of the standard deviation and the interquartile range
> divided by 1.34 times the sample size to the negative one-fifth
> power (= Silverman's ‘rule of thumb’, Silverman (1986, page 48,
> eqn (3.31))) *unless* the quartiles coincide when a positive
> result will be guaranteed.

And now if we check what happens if `lo` is assigned the value 0?

```
if(!(lo <- 0))
    print("We are now in the TRUE part of the if clause")
```

Comment: you're right, it's a strange way to check whether the output of an expression is 0